# Unit Test case to Mock object to function

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

How Pass **event** Mock object and get validated

```
onCallFunction() {
      const eventValue = event;
            if (!eventValue.relatedTarget || !eventValue.relatedTarget.last.contain('value')) {
                super.onCallFunction();
            }
     }
```

In Testbed declare event const but could not understand how to pass to function to execute the code

```
describe('relatedTarget test', () => {
  compoenent = fixture.componentInstance;

  it('should have value for property newValue', () {
    spyOn('component', 'onCallFunction');
    const event = {event: 
    { 
    relatedTarget: 
    {
     last: { 
      contain: (param) => {} 
     } 
    }
    }};
    component.onCallFunction();
    expect(component.onCallFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not spelled "component" correctly so change the declaration to:

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

You should also wrap that line in a beforeEach as so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

Then change your spy so that is actually spies on the function and declare it as a variable:

```
const spy = spyOn<any>(component, 'onCallFunction');
```

and change the expecation to actually ask the spy if it has been called:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Now the test should pass when you call component.onCallFunction() and expects it to have been called, but i'm having trouble understanding what the "event" variable is meant to do? What are you actually trying to test here?

Comment: event is const property, where i'm trying to set value for this object below:
eventValue.relatedTarget || !eventValue.relatedTarget.last.contain('value')
_current solution is just t verify the method is called but negative scenario I have to test by setting the values to eventValue as mentioned_

Comment: Yeah okay. So a property from where? Does your component compile? As it looks now `const eventValue = event` is not only redundant, it's also undefined.

Comment: event is example I tried to do, is there any way to set value this line in function
`eventValue.relatedTarget || !eventValue.relatedTarget.last.contain('value') `

Comment: onCallFunction could take an input value, so: `onCallFunction(eventValue) {...}`

Comment: But in onCallFunction there is no param onCallFunction(), please see on component section

Comment: It is not really clear what you are doing in your application, what you are trying to achive both with the code and tests so that may not be the solution.. You'll need to clarify what it is you are doing.

Comment: That is related target on element when you focus on element , it clearly there in the ts code